# Using Appium to retrieve log for iOS simulator return partial result

Tags: ios, logging, appium

I use the following command to retrieve device log for Android and iOS. For Android i use "logcat" and for iOS i use "syslog".

```
manage().logs().get().getAll()
```

For Android, the log i am getting contains all the entries i am looking for, such as outgoing events from the device. But for iOS, I am getting only a partial result.

How do i know that? By using XCODE to launch the simulator and install the test application and seeing all the relevant events in the console in XCODE.

Is there another parameter i need to pass, or another tool i can use to get the full log of the simulator, is it seems Appium doesn't have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are writing autotests for some iOS app, and those tests run on simulator. Hope this can help:

### Automated solution

To listen to the app's events, you can use the following commmand:

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --debug  > your_dump_file.txt`

Please note `xcrun simctl spawn booted` is a command only for simulator, not for a real device.
It will write a stream of ALL device events to your file, which you could parse later, until you stop it.

If you are interested in a particular logs from your app, you can "filter" logs:

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --debug --predicate 'subsystem == "com.your-company.AppName"' > your_dump_file.txt`

A "predicate" here is a tag for `os_log`, which you can create in your code:

`static os_log_t customLog = os_log_create("com.your-company.AppName", "com.your-company.AppName");`

And then log events you are particularly interested in:

```
- (void)logButtonTouchDown:(NSString*)buttonID
{
    os_log(customLog, "Button_%s_TouchDown", buttonID.UTF8String);
}
```

If an app is running in Release mode, then you may try adding `{public}` to the run-time values which are "exposed":

```
- (void)logButtonTouchDown:(NSString*)buttonID
{
    os_log(customLog, "Button_%{public}s_TouchDown", buttonID.UTF8String);
}
```

Then, you can process `your_dump_file.txt` and process the logs somehow.

### Manual solution

You can see device log in `Console.app` on MacOS. Please note than you may also need add `{public}` specifier to your logs to see some real values.